# Override prefers-color-scheme in Electron

Tags: css, electron, chromium

I have an Electron app that uses CSS `prefers-color-scheme` to implement dark mode. This works fine on Windows and Mac, but not on Linux (presumably because Chromium doesn't have a way of querying the desktop theme).

I would like to provide an option to override the value that Chromium automatically finds for `prefers-color-scheme`. Is there a way to do this using the Electron API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API! You can [`nativeTheme.themeSource`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-theme#nativethemethemesource) to `system`, `light` or `dark`.

For example, in my `background.ts`, add this code:

```
import { /* existing stuff */, nativeTheme } from "electron";

nativeTheme.themeSource = 'light';
```

Comment: I've never gotten it to work, is it undefined outside of Linux or something?

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to ask you how? `if (app) app.on('ready', function() {
  nativeTheme = electron.nativeTheme;
  nativeTheme.themeSource = 'dark';
});` always crashes into a tree for me on Windows. (`nativeTheme` being undefined.)

Comment: I pretty much did the same thing but put it at the top level. I assume you're using Typescript (if not you should fix that now!) - do you get a type error for `electron.nativeTheme`? Might be worth posting more of your code in a new question.

Comment: Good suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633484/electron-trying-to-set-nativetheme-themesource-but-nativetheme-is-undefine if you feel like taking a crack at it. And no, I'm an old dog and Typescript is a new trick :) Frankly I considered Javascript to be a fad until about 10 years after node came along. PS, thanks for adding a code sample :)